# react native gesture handler with android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

invariant violation requirenativecomponent RNGestureHandlerRootview was not found  in the ui manager when integrating react  application bundle in existing android application.
When i individually run the react native app it works fine but when integrated with android ap it gives error.